# how to make snippets and syntax hightlighting work with preprocessors? like .js.haml or .js.erb

Tags: sublimetext2

If I have a `.js` or a `.haml` or `.erb` file, the snippets work great.

But if I create a `.js.haml` or something like that. then I don't get Javascript syntax highlighting or snippets.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to `view` > `syntax` > `open all with current extension as...` > `JavaScript` > `JavaScript`.